# Android. Nested recyclerview scrolling itself when traverse through parent recycler

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-tv

**Update:**
 I decide to create a github repo with this issue to anyone can try to reproduce it and try to fix it.
 https://github.com/LolusKekus/NestsedRecyclerScrollItselfChallenge

---

**Update2**
Spending some time in research i'm finally find a solution thats feet my demands.

All i need is **extend recyclerview** class and **override forcusSearch** method as follo:

```
    @Override
    public View focusSearch(View focused, int direction) {
        View view = super.focusSearch(focused, direction);
        Log.d(TAG, "focusSearch: ");
        if (view instanceof CRecyclerView) {
            int position = ((LinearLayoutManager)((CRecyclerView) view).getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            view = ((CRecyclerView) view).getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(position);
        }

        return view;
    }
```

CRecyclerView - my extended RecyclerView.

In normal conditions focusSearch returns my itemview and everything is fine. But for some reasons focusSearch return RecyclerView instance and as result i have this annoying auto scroll. I don't dig deeper in this problem cause i've got all i need. But if someone can, I'll be appreciate.

---

I have vertical recycler with a bunch of nested horisontal recyclers.
When i'm scrolling over vertical recycler, nested recyclers scroll themself without any reason.

It's looks like this.
Before scroll, let's imagine that selector on 31:

```
_____________
|31 32 33 34|
|41 42 43 44|
|51 52 53 54|
_____________
```

now press up on dpad (i'm working on android tv app):

```
_____________
|24 25 26 27|
|31 32 33 34|
|41 42 43 44|
_____________
```

Hidden recyclerview appears, binds and scrolls up to 24 element. But it mustn't be! The selected item must be 21! And so on until the top of vertical recycler... 14... 04...

I'm noticed, nested recycler scrolls just to last visible item on it.

this behavior appears after **"com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1"**

Now i'm using **"com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1"** and faced with this issue.

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<String> hDataset;
    List<Integer> vDataset;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        hDataset = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<hItemsCount; i++) {
            hDataset.add(String.format("lolKek Cheburek %d", i));
        }

        vDataset = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<vItemsCount; i++) {
            vDataset.add(i);
        }

        vRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.vRecyclerView);
        vRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        vRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        vRecyclerView.setAdapter(new VAdapter(vDataset, hDataset, context));
}
```

Vertical adapter:

```
public class VAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VAdapter.MyVertHolder>() {
    private List<String> hDataset;
    private Context context;

    public VAdapter(List<String> hDataset, List<String> vDataset, Context context) {
       this.hDataset = hDataset;
       this.vDataset = vDataset;
       this.context = context;
    }

    public static class MyVertHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        RecyclerView hRecyclerView;

        public MyVertHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            hRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hRecyclerView);
        }

        public void setAdapter(HAdapter adapter) {
            hRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        public void setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager) {
            hRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyVertHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.v_item_view, parent, false);

        MyVertHolder holder = new MyVertHolder(itemView);
        holder.setAdapter(new HAdapter(hDataset));
        holder.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManage(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final @NonNull MyVertHolder holder, int position) {
        ... some bindings
    }
}
```

Horisontal adapter:

```
class HAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HAdapter.MyHolder> {
    private List<String> dataset;
    public HAdapter(List<String> dataset) {
        this.dataset = dataset;
    }

    public static class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView tvItemText;

        public MyHolder(FrameLayout itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvItemText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemText);
        }
    }

@Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        FrameLayout itemView = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater
.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
        return new MyHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final @NonNull MyHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.setItemText(dataset.get(position));
}
```

main activity layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="MainActivity">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/vRecyclerView"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

vertical item view layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/hRecyclerView"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

horisontal item view layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flContainer"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvItemText"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I want stop this annoying auto scroll behavior.
Thanks.

Comment: None of the answers help yet. I decide to create a github repo with this issue to anyone can try to reproduce it and try to fix it.
https://github.com/LolusKekus/NestsedRecyclerScrollItselfChallenge

Answer (score 0):

please remove

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

and let me know the status.

Comment: Nested horisontal feed stops focusing. But also nested horizontal recyclers stop scrolling when traverse over parent vertical recycler.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your HAdapter class

```
private View.OnKeyListener mOnKeyListener = new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) v.getParent();
       if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP) {
           rv.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0);
       }          
       return false;
    }
};
```

and

```
itemView.setOnKeyListener(mOnKeyListener);
```

into the `onCreateViewHolder` method of your HAdapter class.

This one is only for the Arrow Up key, you can extend the if clause to include the Arrow Down key as well.

**Edit:**

Alternatively, you can put that into the if clause instead of scrollToPosition method call:

```
private View.OnKeyListener mOnKeyListener = new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) v.getParent();
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP) {
           int pos = rv.getLayoutManager().getPosition(v);
           rv.scrollBy(-((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, pos * width, mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics())), 0);
        }          
        return false;
    }
};
```

where width is the width of the RecyclerView item(s) in dp.

**Suggestion:**

I would move the setAdapter and setLayoutManager methods from the ViewHolder class into the HAdapter class body. (Do the same in the VAdapter class as well) They have nothing to do with the ViewHolder pattern. ViewHolder pattern is used to optimize performance by caching the views returned by findViewById()

**Edit 2:**

Add this class to your project:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wuakitv/leanback-v17/master/src/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/PersistentFocusWrapper.java

Then, modify your v_item_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<lolkek.example.com.testrecycler.PersistentFocusWrapper
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/hRecyclerView"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</lolkek.example.com.testrecycler.PersistentFocusWrapper>
```

I tested it, and it works.

Comment: rv.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0); - problem here is that i don't need to scroll to first element every time.

Comment: See the section Edit 2 in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the state/position of each Horizontal RecyclerView's Adapter. When you are scrolling the vertical RecyclerView you are, obviously, recycling the views, therefor, if the horizontal adapter's state is not saved, when you scroll the vertical RecyclerView you will end up in some position for a scrolled Horizontal RecyclerView different than the one you were before the view was recycled.

Comment: Unfortunatly i'ts not working. Nested horizontal recyclers keep scrolling on their own.

Comment: In theory should work. Maybe you should debug it to understand whats going on. Also check the vertical recyclerview recycling, the problem could be there

Comment: Yes, you right. Horizontal recycler don't scroll now, but focus keep moving to last visible item.